# Where to put the file logstash.conf in python source?

Tags: python, logstash, kibana

My main purpose is to send log to `Kiabana`, I was given a `host` and `port` of the `Logstash` (my boss gave me)

From this website: `https://pypi.org/project/python-logstash/` I have an example code like this:

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = '182.2....'

test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))
# test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))

test_logger.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
test_logger.warning('python-logstash: test logstash warning message.')

# add extra field to logstash message
extra = {
    'test_string': 'python version: ' + repr(sys.version_info),
    'test_boolean': True,
    'test_dict': {'a': 1, 'b': 'c'},
    'test_float': 1.23,
    'test_integer': 123,
    'test_list': [1, 2, '3'],
}
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test extra fields', extra=extra)
```

I ran it but I see nothing on the Kibana. ( I was told to choose the `index`) but I see no `index` set up on the example code.

Then after research, I heard that I need to set up a file called `logstash.conf` configuration which should looks like this

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 5959
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

But I dont know where to put that file,

Should it in the same directory with my `.py` code file.

And I dont see any connection between my `.py` code file and `logstash.conf` file

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python-logstash lib you are using is a lib to help you send data to logstash, it has nothing to do with the `logstash.conf` you pasted.

The `logstash.conf` that you shared is a Logstash config, it should be in the config directory of Logstash, but this config will not send anything to Elasticsearch and you will see nothing in Kibana, you need a configuration that will output to elasticsearch, something like this.

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 5959
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["your-elasticsearch-host:port"]
    index => "your-index-name"
  }
}
```

You or someone in your company needs to create a pipeline in Logstash to receive data in that port and send it to Elasticsearch, this way you can use Kibana to visualize the data.

Your python script just need the port and host for logstash to send the data, there is no connection between your python script and logstash configuration besides that.